# We've selected our Moderators Pro Tempore

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Christophe Strobbe]
[image: Flimzy]
[image: Tom Au]
[image: Hatchet]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections once the site graduates.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Our policy is normally to only select 3 pro-tem moderators. However, one of the moderators was absent when the initial invitation was sent out, only to respond at the same time as we selected a new choice. Ergo, we appointed 4 this time around.

Comment: This is only so awesome. I'm pretty sure there were much more people that waited for this post more than me. Congratulations to Flimzy, Quill, Tom and Hatchet!

Answer (score 11):

Congrats to everyone who ran! I'm sure our site will be in great hands with these great moderators! Here's to the next year(s) ahead until we reach graduation!

Comment: Pssst! LLSE has a new moderator!

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Congratulations! If I may ask, did Quill resign?

Comment: I suppose he/she did, but StackExchange did not mention any names in the e-mail they sent me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this answer to document how the moderator team has evolved over the years.

#### Original Moderator Team (June 2016)

- [image: Quill]
- [image: Flimzy]
- [image: Tom Au]
- [image: Hatchet]

#### Moderator Team Starting 27 October 2017

- [image: Flimzy]
- [image: Tom Au]
- [image: Hatchet]
- [image: Tsundoku]

#### Moderator Team Starting 26 July 2019

- [image: Tom Au]
- [image: Hatchet]
- [image: Tsundoku]

(See [Flimzy's goodbye post](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/800).)

#### Moderator Team Starting 23 October 2019

- [image: Tom Au]
- [image: Tsundoku]

(See [Hatchet's goodbye post](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/662/800).)

#### Moderator Team after the July 2021 Election

- [image: Tom Au]
- [image: Tsundoku]
- [image: fi12]

(See the [2021 Community Moderator Election Results](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/711/800), 27 July 2021.)

#### Moderator Team Starting 8 July 2022

- [image: Tom Au]
- [image: Tsundoku]