# It's been fun, but it's time to turn in my diamond

Tags: discussion

Those of you who have been here since the beginning may remember that I was very active on this site initially, as one of the original pro-tem moderators. But just recently I've turned in my diamond, as I've been largely absent for several months now.

Since this site first appeared, my life has taken several interesting turns (marriage, living in a new country, more than one job change), but none of them have kept me as involved with language study as I had been before.

I've been happy to see several initiatives on this site, to increase engagement.

I will no doubt pop in from time to time, and if I have the time to do more language study in the future, I'll probably be ask with more questions.

In the mean time, keep up the good work!

Cheers,

Jonathan

Comment: Thank you for your hard work and dedication! Hope to see your new posts here.

Comment: Thanks for all your contributions!

Comment: Thanks for your contributions, both in the form of questions and answers, and as a moderator. And for those who've never been on [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning), don't forget that Flimzy originally proposed this site!