# I will be going inactive as a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation, stackexchange

You have probably seen many similar posts like this across all of Stack Exchange. I'll keep this brief.

I do not support Stack Exchange in their poorly executed venture into forced language, gender politics and their reprehensible behavior towards the community and moderators, let alone the fact that they blatantly smeared the reputation of one of their top moderators.

I am not an employee, agent, or representative of Stack Exchange Inc.

I was very disappointed in Stack Exchange a week or so ago, but I am taking this action because Stack Exchange has (as of the time of writing) performed *very stunningly little* to rectify the situation beyond posting on meta and on their blog, which I find disgusting, at the very least.

I no longer trust Stack Exchange.

I will be going inactive as a moderator.

Thanks for all the fish.

Comment: Completely reasonable choice, given the circumstances.

Comment: On Literature Stack Exchange, Mithical had [resigned in October 2019](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1200/2191) and asked to be [reinstated last month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/picking-up-my-diamond-once-again). Things have changed.