# Goodbye, friends

Tags: discussion, moderation

As you may know, [I suspended activity on SE](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/662/85) some time ago as a response to Monica being fired.

Today, I submitted my resignation from moderating due to [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342031/338400) and [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342079/338400) also losing their positions.

Goodbye.

Comment: Are you staying on as a normal user or does your resignation also imply that you will delete your account (as some other ex-mods have done)?

Comment: @IkWeetHetOokNiet I don't think it's necessary for me to delete my account, but I will not be unsuspending activity.