# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Language Learning has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: fi12]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4918493926391808).

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations to fi12 on winning the moderator election (with a "landslide victory", as they say in some parts of the world).

Also a big thank you to [Rebecca J. Stones](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2795/rebecca-j-stones) and [Ken Graham](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/794/ken-graham) for nominating themselves when none of the 2000+ rep users had yet stepped up to the plate!

Comment: Tsundoku, you are more than welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your votes, everyone! I'm happy to join the Language Learning moderation team and continue helping to improve our site.

Comment: Congratulations!  (:

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations **fi12**. May your tenor a moderator be both enjoyable as well as rewarding!

Comment: Thanks for your wishes and for partaking in the process Ken.